# How to use TransmitFile with HttpListener

Tags: c#, httplistener

I have HTTP server written using HttpListener and want zero-copy technology for sending files to clients.

Is there are any option to use TransmitFile to respond?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to [`HttpResponse.TransmitFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/12s31dhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? HttpListener doesn't buffer the response content, so you just need to write directly to the output stream.

You can use an extension method like this to mimic the ASP.NET behavior:

```
public static void TransmitFile(this HttpListenerResponse response, string fileName)
{
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        response.ContentLength64 = fileStream.Length;
        fileStream.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpResponse.TransmitFile uses [TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/12s31dhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It works like this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/j-zerocopy/ . And this is the exact behavior I want. But I can't find this option using HttpListener.

Comment: @eccentric, this option doesn't exist in HttpListener, which is why I suggested an extension method that does the same thing...